# JQuery Smooth Scroll in Navigation

Tags: jquery

I looked through a lot of other posts on this and tried putzing around with this and for whatever reason it's still not working:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").on("click", function(event) {
            var hash = $(this).data("hash");
            if (hash) {
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $(document.getElementById(hash)).offset().top
                }, 800, function() {
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav-bar-in">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/Home" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Start">Start</a></li>
        <li><a href="#more">More</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<a name="more"></a>
```

Comment: It's working when I try. Are you sure you have an element with an id corresponding to the hash?

Comment: I mean --  if I literally cut and paste what I have above it doesn't work for me in either Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: That is because you need to have an element somewhere on the page with a corresponding id. You have `<a href="#test">` then you need a corresponding `<p id="test"></p>`

Comment: I just edited my original to more accurately show what I'm working with; what I originally had was a more bare bones for clarity, but maybe this will help.